# How to create a row of buttons with single active button at a time

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

My first question!

I'm looking to create a single row of text-filled buttons in XAML (kind of like this, but without the icons: http://bootsnipp.com/img/screenshots/0f277634083d2f5fd6c1bb54688da5b9b39bbc26.png), one of which can be selected at a time, similar to radio buttons. The RadioButton control has the right functionality, but the wrong aesthetic, and none of the styles or templates I've made seem to work correctly.

Is there any other control that would provide me with a way to create this row of buttons that keeps the functionality of the RadioButton? Or is there a way to template out the RadioButton so it looks like a text filled button?

Thanks!

Comment: Either use RadioButtons or a TabControl, depending on what you need to do with the buttons. Either way, simply change the ControlTemplate. What have you tried?

Comment: So far I've tried changing the template of RadioButtons arrayed in a horizontal Grid, but the resulting "button" never fits within the Grid column, regardless of changes to width and alignment in the template or RadioButton itself. I've looked at just modifying the default template for the RadioButton, but I'm still new to XAML and the default template is terrifying. I've searched all over for a relevant tutorial on the subject, but most seem to be in WPF, which doesn't work for WinPhone 8 development as far as I know.

Comment: WPF's XAML and WinRT/Windows Phone XAML are conceptually the same, but there's slight implementation differences. In any case, you should post the relevant XAML of what you already tried and a screenshot of how it's not ok or the like.

Comment: After a bit more digging, it looks like the combobox will also also fulfill my needs, so I think I'll leave this particular styling challenge for another day. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Designing custom templates is hard :-), especially if you want to deal correctly with all possible state transitions (you can't change the same property of an object across different groups). Here's one I threw together for you though; there are a couple of TODOs if you want to change simple stuff (if you're more adventurous you can change other things, too).

First, the XAML: Paste this into your page, replacing everything except the opening and closing tags of the `PhoneApplicationPage` itself. You can also move the `Resources` to your `App.xaml` file if you want to use the style elsewhere:

```
  <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TabControl" TargetType="RadioButton">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
      <!--TODO: Change this BorderBrush if you want a different colour-->
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#4060ff"/>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
      <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
      <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
      <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}"/>
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Grid Background="Transparent">
              <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                  <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                  <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                  <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBorder">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                  <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledBorder">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckedBorder">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckedBorder">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                  <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckedBorder">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledBorder">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                  <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                  <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                </VisualStateGroup>
              </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

              <!--TODO: Change this Margin if you don't like the big gaps between things-->
              <Grid Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                <Border x:Name="PressedBorder" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Background="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Opacity="0.75" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <Border x:Name="CheckedBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                <Border x:Name="DisabledBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
      <Grid x:Name="container">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <RadioButton Content="home" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource TabControl}" IsChecked="True"/>
        <RadioButton Content="stuff" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource TabControl}" />
        <RadioButton Content="info" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource TabControl}" />
        <RadioButton Content="more..." Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource TabControl}" />
      </Grid>
      <CheckBox x:Name="toggle" Content="show disabled" Checked="toggle_Checked" Unchecked="toggle_Unchecked"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
```

Now a little bit of code to show enable / disable state:

```
private void toggle_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  foreach (var control in container.Children)
    (control as RadioButton).IsEnabled = false;
}

private void toggle_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  foreach (var control in container.Children)
    (control as RadioButton).IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: I will definitely try this once I get the code behind files done. Thank you for the guidance!!!